# R Shiny apps as native iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, r, iphone, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app that is of course easily viewable on mobile (iphone etc)

But what options do I have If I wanted to create a native app on iOS but utilize Shiny and R

I was thinking 
1. I could host it on shinyapps servers. and then some how find a way to link my url to a native app on Iphone

2. simply keep it as a browser url based app and save the link on Iphone

Do any of you know how I could utilize R, Shiny and host it on Iphone as an app